# Element name or type as argument to XmlElementAttribute in System.Xml.Serialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, attributes, deserialization

While using `XmlSerializer` to deserialize

**Case 1:**
`Presentation` contains child element(s) of type `Slide`

```xml
<Presentation>
    <Slide>
        ...
    </Slide>
</Presentation>
```

`nameof` fetches the correct result, i.e. `elementName` should be passed. Replacing it with `typeof` gives incorrect result.

```cs
public class Presentation
{
    ...
    [XmlElement(nameof(Slide))]
    public List<Slide> Slides { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**Case 2:**
`Slide` contains child element(s) of type `TextBox` or `Table` derived from a base class `Shape`

```xml
<Slide>
    <TextBox>
        ...
    </TextBox>
    <Table>
        ...
    </Table>
</Slide>
```

`typeof` fetches the correct result, i.e. `type` should be passed. Replacing it with `nameof` gives incorrect result.

```cs
public class Slide
{
    ...
    [XmlElement(typeof(TextBox))]
    [XmlElement(typeof(Table))]
    public List<Shape> Shapes { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Can anyone explain the above? When to provide element name and when to provide type?

Comment: I'm confused as to what is actually being asked here. Is there just confusion between what `typeof` and `nameof` do? Both [nameof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69108951/nameof-vs-typeof-in-system-xml-serialization) and [typeof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#typeof-operator) have great documentation.

Comment: Not really. The XML isn't deserialized correctly if the respective is not done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the C# attributes, `XmlSerializer` constructor generates a pair of classes derived from `XmlSerializationReader` and `XmlSerializationWriter` by analysis of the classes using reflection<sup>[[1](https://www.careerride.com/Csharp-how-does-XmlSerializer-work.aspx)]</sup>. A mapping between the element names in the XML and types in C# is then also established<sup>[[2](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs)]</sup>.

When `XmlElementAttribute(string elementName, Type type)` is used on a collection, each attribute corresponds to one such mapping. This is subject to following logic for each attribute

- When type is not specified, it is inferred from the type of the element in the collection
- ​If one or no attribute is specified (collection of objects of same type)

  - When name is not specified, it is inferred from the name of the property
- If two or more attributes are specified (collection of objects of different types)

  - When name is not specified, it is inferred from the **name of the type provided to or inferred by the attribute**

This also has been stated in the [documentation of XmlAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute?view=net-5.)

> Note that when you apply the XmlElementAttribute multiple times without specifying an ElementName property value, the elements are named after the type of the acceptable objects.

Now with reference to the OP,

**Case 1:**

```cs
[XmlElement(nameof(Slide))]
```

is similar to

```cs
[XmlElement("Slide", typeof(Slide))]
```

replacing it with `typeof` would be similar to

```cs
[XmlElement("Slides", typeof(Slide))]
```

which would mean we need to specify `"Slides"` as the element name in the XML and not `"Slide"`, hence the incorrect result.

**Case 2:**

```cs
[XmlElement(typeof(TextBox))]
[XmlElement(typeof(Table))]
```

is similar to

```cs
[XmlElement("TextBox", typeof(TextBox))]
[XmlElement("Table", typeof(Table))]
```

replacing it with `nameof` would be similar to

```cs
[XmlElement("TextBox", typeof(Shape))]
[XmlElement("Table", typeof(Shape))]
```

Here, there is ambiguity as to what to map for the type `Shape`, between `TextBox` and `Table`. Hence, the mapping itself cannot be established and the code exits.